# Object creation strange behaviour

Tags: c#

1. I have a class "Animals" which contains instance variable name and a set method accordingly

   public void setName(string newName)
   {
   name = newName;
   }
2. I have other childclasses that inherits from "Animals"
3. I create an object from one of these and add it to my List< Animals > accordingly:

   ```
   Turtle anAnimal = new Turtle();

   //add to list

   list.Add(anAnimal);
   ```
4. I assign properties in relation to every class like this:

   ```
    //assigning all values

    //bird info
    foreach (var Animals in list.OfType<Birds>())
    {

        Animals.setFeatherColor(feather_color);
        Animals.setWingspan(wingspan);
    }
    //reptile info
    foreach (var Animals in list.OfType<Reptiles>())
    {
        Animals.setScalesColor(scales_color);
        Animals.setVenemous(Venemous);

    }
    //animal info
    foreach (var Animals in list.OfType<Animals>())
    {
        Animals.setId(list);
        Animals.setAge(age);
        Animals.setDiet(diet);
        Animals.setGender(gender);
        Animals.setName(name);
    }
   ```

5.This is where the problem is:
Animals.setName(name) assigns the **same value** every time I create a new animal with **different names**

6.name comes from textbox.Text;

Why is this happening? thank you
(I am not forgetting to change textbox.Text)

Comment: As we don't see all the relevant code (e.g., how sub-classes of animal are defined and the calling code), it's hard to tell. I'd suggest 1) add more debugging (either manually, breakpoint + step by step, or add logs to the console) and 2) try to simplify your program until the issue does not arise anymore (e.g., keep only one child class, keep only the text property etc...  weed out as much code as possible). See also [mcve]

Comment: also, are there any warnings showing in Visual Studio ? (in the panel where you see compilation Errors, need to enable a filter, it can point to something smelly)

Comment: First of try to follow C# coding standards this looks like Java code. Use properties or standard Pascal case for names. My guess is the problem is a stale closure reference but you need to add more code to see where the problem is.

Comment: Your code indeed assigns the same `name` to all the animals in `list`.

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase. You should rename `Animals` to `animal`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a lot of code missing, yet my understanding is that you have a superclass called `Animals` and a series of derived classes `Bird`, `Reptile` and such... so when you call `Animals.SetName(name)` you're calling it within a `foreach` loop that won't actually filter anything, since all of your classes are derived from the `Animals` class.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal { }

public class Reptile : Animal { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Animal> animals= new List<Animal>();
    Bird bird = new Bird();
    bird.name = "bird";
    Reptile reptile = new Reptile();
    reptile.name = "reptile";
    animals.Add(bird); animals.Add(reptile);

    foreach (var animal in animals.OfType<Animal>()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(animal.name); // writes 'bird', 'reptile' 
    }
}
```

Comment: -then why do    Animals.setId(list);
                                         Animals.setAge(age);
                                         Animals.setDiet(diet);
                                         Animals.setGender(gender);

                - work while setName() doesn't?
                 
               The set methods are defined exactly the same. Very confusing..
                I did solve this problem by setting name when I create a new object,
                but this should work....